# using a socket to print raw text

Tags: java, android, sockets

i'm working on an application to print to my local wifi printers but over 9100 port i have no response, over the 515 i have "connection refused".

the code is this:

```
Socket test = new Socket();
Socket sock = new Socket(ip,9100);
PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

oStream.printf("========================\n");
oStream.printf("PROVA STAMPA\n");
oStream.printf("HELLO SLOW SUD\n");
oStream.printf("========================"+"\n");

oStream.close();
sock.close();
```

and also i have try this:

```
Socket objSocket = new Socket();

InetSocketAddress objEndPoint = new InetSocketAddress(ip, 9100);

DataOutputStream objOutputStream;

objSocket.connect(objEndPoint, 6000);

objOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(objSocket.getOutputStream());
objOutputStream.write(("========================\nPROVA STAMPA\nHELLO SLOW SUD\n========================\n").getBytes());

objOutputStream.close();
objSocket.close();
```

Comment: What line of code is failing?

Comment: i don't know, simply the printer does't send response